Movie about a troubled teen that sounds something like "oriander" or "coriander"
I saw a movie a few years back (more than 5-6 years for sure, but the movie could be older).
All I can recollect is,there's a teenage girl who was simple and sober in the
beginning but later on she went somewhere(I don't remember where,maybe a hostel or something).  She may have lost her dad or something, perhaps he was killed, I don't remember.
A few years later (this is the scene I can remember), she is sitting in front of her mom, smoking and talking abusively.
The good part is, I am sure the movie sounds something like "oriander" or "coriander" (sorry for those funny words).

Is it White Oleander? You can see the plot summary here. It concerns a girl's experience in foster care homes while communicating to her imprisoned mother.
It was the first thing that came to mind due to the similarity of the title to your word hint.
